# Ideal merge for different number of columns and rows in dataframe

Tags: r

Some example data of stucture:

```
df1 = data.frame(x=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
df2 = data.frame(x=c('f', 'g', 'h'),y = c(0,1,0))
df3 = data.frame(x=c('i', 'j','k','l'), y = c(1,7,5,2,6), z = c(75,3,25,2,1))
```

I have 3 different dataframes.

df1 has 22201 object and 121 variables
df2 has 8403 object and 68 variables
df3 has 50476 object and 157 variables

I try to merge them using merge and I receive this error:

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
  'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical
```

using cbind and I received this error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 22201, 8403, 50476
```

and rbind and I receive this error:

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

How can I merge dataframes with different number of rows and columns? I have to refer that columns have the same names in dataframes so in the merge I expect the number of columns be the highest numbers of columns of the dataframe which contains the most.

Comment: Can you show us your code and a reproducible example of your dataframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, use `rbind.fill` from the library `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(df1, df2, df3)
```

This will `merge` all your 3 `data frames` with different number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` is an evolution from `plyr`, so I'd use it instead.
`bind_rows` will achieve what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, ...)
```

One example:

```
tbl1 <- data_frame(var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
                   var2 = c('x', 'y', 'z'))

tbl2 <- data_frame(var1 = c('e', 'd', 'g', 'h'))

tbl3 <- data_frame(var6 = 1, 
                   var10 = 14)

> bind_rows(tbl1, tbl2, tbl3)
# A tibble: 8 x 4
   var1  var2  var6 var10
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a     x    NA    NA
2     b     y    NA    NA
3     c     z    NA    NA
4     e  <NA>    NA    NA
5     d  <NA>    NA    NA
6     g  <NA>    NA    NA
7     h  <NA>    NA    NA
8  <NA>  <NA>     1    14
```